# R: Separating a column in a csv file based on a Time Variable

Tags: r

I have a csv file, June_8th with 2 columns, a time stamp, V1 (hour:minute:second)(01:55:41) and an ID number, V2 (Not really important at this stage). I want to separate the data in 24 different sections based on the hour of the time stamp. And then find the count of how many time stamps were in each hour.

My code I've attempted is:

```
Time_2am = subset(June_8th, V1 >= 02:00:00 & V1 < 03:00:00)
```

I keep getting warning message stating:

> 1: In 2:0:0 : numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first one
>   used
>
> 2: In Ops.factor(V1, 2:0:0) : '>=' not meaningful for factors
>
> 3: In 3:0:0 : numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first one
>   used
>
> 4: In Ops.factor(V1, 3:0:0) : '<' not meaningful for factors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to separate your data in 24 sections based on the hour of the timestamp, you could extract the hours with:

```
library(lubridate)
hour(hms(June_8th$V1))
```

which gives:

```
> hour(hms(June_8th$V1))
[1] 1 2 3
```

If you want to subset your data, then you can do:

```
June_8th[hour(hms(June_8th$V1)) == 2,]
```

which gives:

```
        V1 V2
2 02:35:51  2
```

In base R you can achieve the same result with:

```
# create an hour variable

> format(strptime(paste('2016-06-08', June_8th$V1), format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), '%H')
[1] "01" "02" "03"

# subset the data to select only the time between 02:00:00 and 03:00:00

> June_8th[format(strptime(paste('2016-06-08', June_8th$V1), format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), '%H') == '02',]
        V1 V2
2 02:35:51  2
```

---

Used data:

```
June_8th <- data.frame(V1 = c('01:55:41','02:35:51','03:09:34'), V2 = 1:3)
```

Comment: I'm still getting 2 warning messages:

1: In Ops.factor(June_8th$V1. "3H 0M 0S") : '<' not meaningful for factors

2: In .parse_hms(. . . , order = "HMS", quiet) :

Some strings failed to parse

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

1. `02:00:00` doesn't stand for a timestamp - it is, in fact, equivalent to `(2:0):0`, in which `2:0` is the same as the vector `c(2, 1, 0)`, and by doing another operation `:`, you are trying to create a vector starting with `c(2, 1, 0)` and ends with `0`, which doesn't make sense, so R only use the first value from the vector, namely `2` and the second argument `0`, which gives the vector `c(2, 1, 0)`.
2. You timestamp seem to have the type factor (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/factor.html). They can't be compared with the usual comparison operators, and their levels might not correspond to order of the actual timestamp.

What you can do, is to cast the timestamp to string and then do the comparison with another string, e.g., use `as.character(V1) > '02:00:00'`.